# Clarification on a reflexive function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations, reflection

$R_1 = \{(a, b)  |  a ≤ b\}$ is a reflexive function, but I'm confused on why it is. $a≤b$ but doesn't that not necessarily mean that there is an $a$ that will equal $b$? Couldn't all of the $a$ very well just be less than the $b$?

Comment: A relation $R$  is reflexive if every element is $R$-related to itself. Not if there is some *other* element which is equal to the first element (which doesn't make any sense, since if it's equal to the element, then it's not some *other* element).

Comment: It's a *relation* not a function.